# How to delete a LocalDB file after use - Not just delete the DB - remove MDF and LDF files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, localdb

I am creating a temporary localDB file with EF via

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SomeDbContext>());
```

I use it to store data instead of a List because there are, well, lots...

This is a temporary DB that I need to cleanup and delete once the process finishes. If it always ran in the same directory, it would be no big deal to let it create / overwrite each time and just leave the 2 files... but the process creates folders for what is being processed and these get left behind, and they can get quite large.

I tried:

```
ctx.Database.Delete();
```

which works for deleting the database, but I also want to remove the .mdf and .ldf files...

so when I run (outside the using block)

```
        if (File.Exists(dbFilePath))
        { 
            File.Delete(dbFilePath); 
        }
```

I get an error:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\path\SomeDB.mdf' because it is being used by another process.

so I tried another option:

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(@"ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", dbFilePath));
```

Error:

> ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.

So, I am looking for a way to close all connections to be able to delete the MDF and LDF files.

Comment: You may want to try calling `Dispose()` on your db context -> (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3cebcee7-1ebc-46ed-aab9-ad2d472e9b9b/how-do-i-quotclosequot-the-connection-to-a-database-mdf-file?forum=adodotnetentityframework). I tried finding these "special cases" where it's necessary, but wasn't able to find anything concrete. Worst case scenario, this doesn't make a difference and you just remove it from your code.

Comment: I tried that, got an error The process cannot access the file C:\path\SomeDB.mdf' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I didn't post enough code for someone to see the problem...

My code actually had:

```
ctx.Database.Delete();
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

After some more digging around, apparently the SaveChanges() keeps a connection open.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb738582(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

> Calling any of the following methods opens the connection:
>
> **SaveChanges** or Refresh on ObjectContext.
>
> FirstOrDefault, or First on ObjectQuery.
>
> Load on EntityCollection.
>
> Load on EntityReference.

Anyway, it also appears that I don't even need the check for files to manually delete them. It seems that after the database is delete and processing continues/finishes/exists program... at some point.. too tired to check exactly when, that it also deletes those files.